# AuthenticationPrincipal is null only with Postman request

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, okta

I am trying run below application in my local(with necessary config changes related to OKTA)
https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-security-authentication-example/tree/master/oauth-okta

All is working fine when application is accessed by browser. authentication is working fine at OKTA and redirected to application correctly.

but when i tried the same API using postman, OidcUser is coming as null.
I generated accessToken from postman with grant_type client_credentials

```
@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser
```

any clues?

-R

Comment: did you find a way for you issue ?

Comment: @Mirlo please see below comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176973/2555212

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from another forum.

My guess is this is how Spring Security works. It will populate this parameter if you login with a browser, but not if you send an access token. You could use the access token to call the /userinfo endpoint and get the user’s information that way. Or you could use Jwt instead of OidcUser, like this example shows.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt) {
    return String.format("Hello, %s!", jwt.getSubject());
}
```